# Is there any option to save the data whenever submit the form in github api json file using react

Tags: html, reactjs

I have fecthed the data from github json but need detail on is ther is any option to store the data in github api in react

Comment: pls provide more info what you mean in `store`, you want to store the data you fetched from github in github? and what you mean using react?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: Actually I need to store the value from form into the github json file when I submit the form using reactJS.